# TypeORM ManyToMany Juntion table create not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, many-to-many, typeorm

I've got two tables `services` and `offers`. an Offer can have many services and a service can have many offers.

My service entity

```
@Entity('Services')
export class ServiceEntity extends BaseEntity {
 
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  serviceKey: number;
  
  ....
  
  @ManyToMany(() => OffersEntity, (offer) => offer.services)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'offersXservices',
    inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: 'offerKey',
        referencedColumnName: 'offerKey'
    },
    joinColumn: {
        name: 'serviceKey',
        referencedColumnName: 'serviceKey',
    },
   })
   offers?: OffersEntity[];

}
```

And My Offers entity is defined like this:

```
@Entity('Offers')
export class OffersEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  offerKey: number;
  
  ....
  
  @ManyToMany(() => ServiceEntity, (service) => service.offers)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'offersXservices',
    inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: 'serviceKey',
        referencedColumnName: 'serviceKey'
    },
    joinColumn: {
        name: 'offerKey',
        referencedColumnName: 'offerKey',
    },
   })
   services?: ServiceEntity[];
}
```

I'm getting an error when I tried to create an offer record with some services : `query failed: INSERT INTO "offersXservices"("offerKey", "serviceKey") VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT) error: error: null value in column "offerKey" violates not-null constraint`.

I don't understand why this is happening? in the above generated query the `DEFAULT` should be replaced with offerKey and serviceKey respectively. can anyone help me on that?

Here is the code which I use to insert into offer record.

```
const _offerEntity = await OffersEntity.create({
            vendorKey: input.vendorKey,
            name: input.name,
            description: input.description,
            startAt: input.startAt,
            expiry: input.expiry,
            services: await ServiceEntity.find({
                where: {
                    serviceKey: In(input.services)
                }
            })
        });

 await queryRunner.manager.save(_offerEntity);
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

PS: Database is postgresql

Comment: Make sure service exist in the database

Comment: @HareshMakwana, Yes it exists. The problem is with raw sql generated by the typeorm.

Comment: Try with adding cascade in relationship `@ManyToMany(() => OffersEntity, (offer) => offer.services, {cascade: true})`

Comment: @HareshMakwana I've tried that, still getting same error.

Comment: Remove this `await OffersEntity.create(` and assign the only object to `_offerEntity` and try

Comment: I tried that, no success

Comment: Did you find a solution? I found 4 similar issues on typeorm's github:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3979, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2612, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3320, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2612

Comment: @noamsteiner I posted my workaround as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a proper solution to this question. I ended up using raw `sql` queries with typeorm.

```
for (const _service of input.services) {
   await queryRunner.manager.query(`INSERT INTO "offersXservices"("offerKey", "serviceKey") VALUES (${_offerEntity.offerKey}, ${_service})`);
}
```

Hope it helps someone.